# Google sheets with finviz

Tags: google-sheets

So finviz changed their website making it more difficult to extract data from their site. I am trying to get the date from the analyst ratings table but I get a series of numbers.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A3, "table", 11), 1, 1), "*", "")
```

For this formula where $A3=FB, I get 44218 for the date instead of Jan-22-21.

I don't have any experience with coding so I am just guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested your formula with `$A3=FB`, I confirmed that `Jan-22-21` is obtained in a cell. So unfortunately, in myenvironment, I couldn't replicate your situation.

But, from your question, I think that the number of `44218` is the serial number of `Jan-22-21`. If your Spreadsheet returns `44218` from your formula of `=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A3, "table", 11), 1, 1), "*", "")`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
=TEXT(TO_DATE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A3, "table", 11), 1, 1), "*", "")),"mmm-dd-yy")
```

- In this case, the cell "A3" has the value of `FB`.
- In this formula, it supposes that `=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A3, "table", 11), 1, 1), "*", "")` returns the number of `44218` in the cell.

Result:

[image]

#### Other pattern:

As other pattern, I would like to propose to use `IMPORTXML`. In this case, I thought that the value of `Jan-22-21` might be able to be directly retrieved using a xpath.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A3,"//tr[@class='body-table-rating-neutral'][1]//tr/td[1]")
```

- In this case, the cell "A3" has the value of `FB`.
- XPath is `//tr[@class='body-table-rating-neutral'][1]//tr/td[1]`.

Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [TO_DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239)
- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)
- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Do you know how I would get data from their income statement below?

Comment: @Reggie Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755721/google-sheets-and-finviz-tables

Answer (score 0):

44218 is the same like Jan-22-21

Why?
Because dates are numbers.

Solution
Format 44218 like date from menu