# Google sheets and finviz tables

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets to grab data from finviz. Let's use facebook (FB) for my example.

https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=FB

I randomly entered this combination

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$B1, "table", ), 1, 1), "*", "")
```

I don't know why it returns insider trading when there's no table # for it.

Also, I am trying to figure out how to get data for the income statement table. How do I get this? Is there a way to find out where the table number is?

Comment: When I saw the HTML of your URL, it seems that the table of "income statement" is created by Javascript. In this case, IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML cannot retrieve the table because they cannot run Javascript. This is the current specification. I apologize for this.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a workaround for that in excel?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question of `Is there a workaround for that in excel?`, when I found the solution, I would like to answer it. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your questions soon.